# Why is retour div not in the right bottom corner?

Tags: html, css

the div retour used to be in the right bottom corner of the screen but when i added another div it just disappeared. i tried everything i could think of but nothing worked. i thought that with position absolute it couldn't move.

```
  .retour {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}

.retour a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
  padding: 14px;
}

<div class="retour">
  <a href="../index.html">Retour</a>
</div>

<div class="soundcloud">
  <iframe width= 50% src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/335992324&amp;
          color=#9cb4b6;
          auto_play=true;
          hide_related=false&amp;
          show_comments=true&amp;
          show_user=true&amp;
          show_reposts=false">
</div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML from your page so we can see what you are talking about...

Comment: `position: relative;` -> `position: absolute;`

Comment: Are you trying to position the `retour` div in the lower-right hand corner of some other element? Or the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position element via `right`, `left`, `top` and `bottom` properties only if this element is positioned absolutely (`position: absolute`) or has a fixed position (`position: fixed`). I guess you want `position: absolute`, so here is an example (it's not in the corner because you specified `margin: 20px`):

```css
.retour {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}

.retour a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="retour">
  <a href="">test</a>
</div>
```

### Update

The difference in scroll with `position: absolute`:

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.retour {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}

.retour a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="retour">
  <a href="">test</a>
</div>
```

And `position: fixed`:

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.retour {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
}

.retour a {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.75;
  font-family: impact;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="retour">
  <a href="">test</a>
</div>
```

Comment: commercial suicide it is exactly what i did, i change the postition from absolute to relative after the problem occured and forgot to change it back. as for the margin i know i want it to be 20px from the right and bottom side of the screen

Comment: it worked before fut i added a iframe and then it disappeared

Comment: @ClémentColin, I can't say anything without looking at your code

Comment: i edited the question. and i figured out something: retour is exactly where i would want it to be if the page was the size of the window but if i scroll down it is not all the way to the bottom

Comment: i changed the position to fixed and it is kind of working, it is always on the bottom of the screen but i would be better if it didn't move with the scrolling

Comment: @ClémentColin, elements with `position: fixed` are always at the same position of the screen, they shouldn't move on scroll...

Comment: sorry my english is not very good i meant moving not on the screen but on the page. now it is always on the bottom on the screen but not always on the bottom of the page as i wanted it